# Adding images to eclipse java project using ImageIcon(getClass().getResource()

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

Can anyone help why am I getting error for my Java swing application that makes use of

```
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource()
```

to load images as shown below. Thanks in advance.

Code where error is shown:

```
jButton9.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/folder63.png")));
```

Error description:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at frame.foundation.initComponents(foundation.java:282)
at frame.foundation.<init>(foundation.java:21)
at frame.foundation$127.run(foundation.java:3453)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

PS: I have also added "images" folder as the source folder in my project

Folder Structure:

```
myprojectName  
         |  
         |___src  
         |     |  
         |     |___frame //(is my package)  
         |            |  
         |            |__foundation.java // main class  
         |  
         |__images  
         |    |  
         |    |__folder63.png  
         |    |__d.jpg  
         |    |__e.jpg  
         |    |__f.jpg
```

Comment: To those who approved this edit proposed by @Darshan: Seriously, you need to read what you're reviewing. The editor deleted part of the question, which now no longer makes sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769351/java-getclass-getresourcefile-leads-to-nullpointerexception?rq=1 checked with this but still the error pops up

Comment: @DavidMakogon +1 I put 2 parts back in the question after seeing the attempted edit was already... aceppted ?!

Comment: Be sure to check the case in the path name.  `"/images/folder63.png"` != `"/images/Folder63.png"`

Comment: @AndrewThompson: double checked such things. Its all correct. Still getting error.

Comment: are you using it in Applet?

Comment: @braj no just a java swing application. Iam still studying on that link you provided. But error is still with it.

Comment: have you tried all the options. move the image in some other folder.

Comment: @FelipeAls - nicely done, including both the code and the PS (which actually contained question-specific info).

Comment: @braj : tried in different foldername and is showing the same exception

Comment: please share snapshot of the project structure.

Comment: @braj : i couldnt upload the pic, so i made my folder structure in the question itself.

Comment: the problem is clear. read what I have told you. It's parallel to `src` folder and as I said you it should be under `src` folder. or use `ImageIO.read(new File("images/folder63.jpg"));` as 2nd option mentioned in my post.

Comment: you are not reading my post carefully and you have wasted your 1 hour to figure this issue....

Comment: @Braj: its clear that "images" folder is parrallel with src folder , so i have to use:"  jButton9.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/folder63.png"))); "

Comment: @Braj : tried with the above code , but that exception is still coming.

Comment: now I am afraid. As you have tried other options as well moving image in other folder as well.

Comment: executed finally from that exception.... I think when the execution envnmt is changed from "  CDC- 1.1/ Foundation" to "J2SE 1.5(JRE8)", made the excecution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java in Eclipse: Where do I put files on the filesystem that I want to load using getResource? (e.g. images for an ImageIcon)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270197/java-in-eclipse-where-do-i-put-files-on-the-filesystem-that-i-want-to-load-usin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure image file is present at correct location. It should be under `src/images` folder.

You can try any one based on image location.

```
// Read from same package 
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder63.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
ImageIO.read(new File("images/folder63.jpg"));

// Read from src/images folder
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/folder63.png"))

// Read from src/images folder
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/folder63.png"))
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825)

It's worth reading *Java Tutorial* on [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("image.jpg");
```

Comment: This line of code doesn't make a ton of sense on its own. Try including some more details on how to interface this recommendation with `ImageIcon`, and why adding an InputStream would be helpful over the other ImageIcon constructors.